# Testing Ionic components with react testing library

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, ionic4, react-testing-library

I've recently started working with the new `ionic 4`, which introduces react instead of angular as a language. In my recent projects I was testing my components with `react-testing-library` for react. Especially when it comes to forms and the submission / change of forms. Due to ionic uses their own web-components for the UI instead of native ones (ion-input instead of input) I cannot fire events like change for a value. If I do that, I get the error message, that this element does not have a setter for value. When researching the DOM-tree there is a native input element as a children for the `ion-input` element. It seems they are communicating via `refs` as there is no value present on the native input.

What is the proper way now to change values of fields in a testcase? I also cannot query the native input element with a `querySelector`. It returns and empty object. When instead querying `ion-input`, returns elements.

Thankful for every idea :)

Answer (score 3):

If you are using `onIonChange` event, you will need to fire a custom event for that, e.g:

```js
    const { getByPlaceholderText } = render(...);
    const input = getByPlaceholderText('Input placeholder');

    fireEvent(input, new CustomEvent('ionChange', { detail: { value: 'Text' } }));
```

Comment: Ionic exports a helper library  '@ionic/react-test-utils', which wraps RTU’s fireEvent, and augments it with all the custom Ionic events.  Found in this blog post: https://ionicframework.com/blog/testing-ionic-react-apps-with-jest-and-react-testing-library/

That said, it still doesn't work for me :(



 https://ionicframework.com/blog/testing-ionic-react-apps-with-jest-and-react-testing-library/